# Using cypher or traversal api to match only a single node on extreme sides of a path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have following path in the graph:

```
(:Type1)<-[:RelType1]-(:Type2)<-[:RelType2]-()<-[*]-(centernode)-[*]->()-[:RelType2]->(:Type2)-[:RelType1]->(:Type1)
```

Given `<id>` of `(:Type1)` node on left side, I am able to `MATCH` above path and get corresponding `(:Type1)` node on right side (notice that the path is symmetric and its center is node `(centernode)`). In my usecase we get `<id>`s of `(:Type1)` node, get the corresponding `(:Type1)` node on the other side and then process further.

However it may happen that I get `<id>`s of both nodes of `(:Type1)`. In that case separate queries will be fired starting at corresponding node and will evaluate to the `(:Type1)` node on the other side, thus further execution will continue on both the nodes.

**Q1.** How can I avoid processing both nodes. That is, if given two `<id>`s of `(:Type1)` nodes which reside on extreme sides of same path, how can I ensure only one of the queries starting at one of these nodes matching node on the other side is executed so that only one of those nodes are processed further and other node is say held in temporary buffer to process afterwards (if processing of first node fails).

**Added fact:** Above I have a single path with two `(:Type1)` nodes at its extreme sides. I may have three or more paths emanating from `(centernode)` and ending in `(:Type1)` node. So I want only one of those `(:Type1)` nodes to get processed first, and next `(:Type1)` node will processed only if earlier processing fails.

**Q2.** Is this scenario even possible with pure cypher? Or I have to end up using Neo4J Traversal API? If yes how this can be done, as I have to ensure uniqueness of nodes/relationships visited across two different traveresals.

**Q3.** How can I add path expander in Traversal API to match path of type `(:Type1)<-[:RelType1]-(:Type2)<-[:RelType2]-()`. Should I be doing something like this:

```
at each traversal `next()`
    if (node is of Type1)
        follow <-[:RelType1]-
    if (node is of Type2)
        follow <-[:RelType2]-
```

(Above is pseudocode. I am new to Traversal API. I have went through all docs and examples. So I am guessing inside expander I have to put `if()` filters to check current nodes type and decide which relation type and its direction to expand next. Above pseudocode is meant to indicate that.)

Is this how such cypher can be writting in Traversal API? Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

An old trick is to use node ids to order pairs (`ID(a) < ID(b)`), which filters out "duplicate" results. So if you feed all your source IDs into a single query, you can make use this trick to filter out duplicates:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4] AS sourceIds
UNWIND sourceIds AS sourceId
MATCH (source:Type1)
WHERE ID(source) = sourceId
MATCH
  (source)<-[:RelType1]-(:Type2)<-[:RelType2]-
  ()<-[*]-(centernode)-[*]->()
  -[:RelType2]->(:Type2)-[:RelType1]->(target:Type1)
WHERE ID(source) < ID(target)
RETURN source, target
```

Could this work for your use case?

Comment: The issue is that I wont be getting all source ids at once. So I will get ids at different point in time (as a part of some triggers) and each time I get new source id, I fire up a thread running cypher. The issue will happen when source ids are received at time few micro seconds apart, which will result in more than one cypher to run causing both cyphers match correpsonding node on other side, starting processing on both (or more than two if more than two source ids are received just few micro seconds apart) the source id node.

Comment: @Mahesha999 I am not an expert on the Traversal API myself, but I think the simplest solution then is to use some custom imperative Java code and manage a queue on your own (e.g. a `BlockingQueue`). You will collect the source ids in this queue and also keep track of the target ids that you found. If a new source id was already found (as a target id), simply skip it. Else, run a simple Cypher query for finding the corresponding target.